# Android string.xml Error

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm simply trying to run the tutorial here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html specifically the section where we add the string resource. I've copied the code, but I'm getting the following error ...

```
[2012-02-02 20:35:35 - HelloAndoird] /home/slabounty/workspace/HelloAndoird/res/values/strings.xml:2: error: Found text "
[2012-02-02 20:35:35 - HelloAndoird] /" where item tag is expected"
[2012-02-02 20:35:35 - HelloAndoird] /home/slabounty/workspace/HelloAndoird/res/layout/main.xml:3: error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

Here's the strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello Android! I am a string resource!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Hello, Android</string>
  </resources>
```

and just in case the main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"   
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

I'm guessing it's something obvious, but I've retyped and copied a couple of times as well as removed the spaces before the string tag and the error's the same.

Any ideas?

---

Edit ... here's the Java file ...

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class HelloAndoirdActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Also, the "clean" didn't work, but that was a good idea.

Comment: copied your code and used it working fine with me may i see your java file?

Comment: did you do a project clean? sometimes that resolves weird stuff like this.

Comment: OK, I have no idea, but I copied again and everything seems to work. It may have been some sort of stray character that got in there or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be safe, wrap your `TextView` in a layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I however don't understand why your code is running into trouble. But I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem by changing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```